# how to initialise this distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, posterior, approximation

I am reading a paper by Tom Minka and trying to follow the steps to perform the updates for the Expectation Propagation algorithm. I am having trouble getting the initialisation of the posterior distribution going. So, the first step involves writing out your joint distribution as a product of factors. In my case, I can do the following:

$$
P(\theta, D) = g(\theta) \prod_i f_i(\theta)
$$

where $g(\theta)$ is a multivariate normal with a certain mean ($\mu)$ and a covariance matrix ($\Sigma$). Each of the factors $f_i$ can be written as a normal distribution with a mean ($m$) and a standard deviation ($\sigma$).

Now, the paper ([here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/ep/minka-ep-uai.pdf&ei=qyr6UqumCMbwhQfjvIDoCQ&usg=AFQjCNG3J7r8w3-sI2n_TEG2SlSlq4Roiw&sig2=EMYV-bGRNYzGvudjnH-zBg&bvm=bv.61190604,d.ZG4)) says as the first step, compute the approximate posterior as:

$$
q(\theta) = \frac{g(\theta) \prod_i f_i(\theta)}{\int g(\theta) \prod_i f_i(\theta) d\theta}
$$

Now, I am really confused as how I can do this operation! So, I can initialise the $g(\theta)$ and each of the $f_i(\theta)$ terms with some initial values but how do I compute $q(\theta)$ in the right form. More specifically, if I assume $q(\theta)$ will take the form of a multivariate Gaussian. How do I compute its mean and covariance from this expression?

I have been looking online and it seems that there are some Gaussian identities one can use but none of the papers actually make it explicit as to which ones to use.